# October CMS Directory Exemption

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I am trying to create a single directory that is outside the OctoberCMS system. In the `.htaccess` file I added the line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/.* [NC]
```

which works great for `public/image.gif`, but `public/file.html` doesn't work. It goes to a 404 page, not an apache 404, but one from OctoberCMS.

I was hoping to have at least one directory completely outside the normal structure. I am annoyed that the CMS has completely hijacked the entire domain not leaving any room for anything that isn't part if it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue was twofold. On the one hand, I had to input the line above to enable access to the public folder, but then I also had to add the `.html` extension to the whitelist area. I was thinking that the first directive would have overridden the need for the whitelist, but not so. I now can tweak it as needed for more customization if needed.

```
php_flag opcache.enable Off
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    ##
    ## You may need to uncomment the following line for some hosting environments,
    ## if you have installed to a subdirectory, enter the name here also.
    ##
    # RewriteBase /

    ##
    ## Black list protected files
    ##

    RewriteRule ^themes/.*/(layouts|pages|partials)/.*.htm index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^bootstrap/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^config/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^vendor/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/cms/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/logs/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/framework/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/temp/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^storage/app/uploads/protected/.* index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## White listed folders and files
    ##
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.js$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.map$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ico$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpg$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.jpeg$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.bmp$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.png$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.gif$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.svg$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.css$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.less$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.scss$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.pdf$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.swf$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.txt$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xls$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.eot$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.woff$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.woff2$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ttf$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.flv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.wmv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mp3$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.ogg$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.wav$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.avi$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mov$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mp4$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mpeg$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.webm$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.mkv$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.rar$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.zip$
    ## Add This here
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !docs/.*
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !themes/.*
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L,NC]

    ##
    ## Standard routes
    ##

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```